# Integral question

Tags: calculus, integration

I would like to ask for help with $$\int \cos^3 (x/9) \,dx$$
I got $$9\sin(x/9) - 3\sin^3(x/9) + c$$ but the book gives another answer which I'm not sure how they got to.

Comment: How did you got that solution?.

Answer (score 3):

Observe that

$$cos^3(y)=cos(y)cos^2(y)=\frac{1}{2}cos(y)(1+cos(2y))=\frac{1}{2}(cos(y)+cos(y)cos(2y))$$

In addition,

$$cos(y)cos(2y)=\frac{1}{2}(cos(y)+cos(3y))$$

Thus, 
$$\int cos^3(x/9)dx=9\int cos^3(x/9)d(x/9)=9\int cos^3(y)dy=9\int \frac{1}{2}(cos(y)+\frac{1}{2}(cos(y)+cos(3y)))dy=\frac{3}{4}\int cos(y)dy+\frac{1}{4}\int cos(3y)dy=...$$

I think you can finish it by yourself.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

30 words...30 words...30 words...30 words...30 words...30 words...30 words...30 words...30 words...30 words...30 words...30 words...30 words...30 words...30 words...30 words...30 words...30 words...

I agree with you...

Comment: is everything ok?

Comment: You solution is actually ok. It is just the expressions of your answer and the one given in the textbook differ. When you deal with trigonometric functions it is not rare to encounter this effect.

Answer (score 1):

First use the substitution

$=\int \cos ^3\left(u\right)9du$

$=\int \:9\cos ^3\left(u\right)du$

Now take out the Constant

$=9\int \cos ^3\left(u\right)du$

Now use the reduction rule:
$\int \cos ^n\left(x\right)dx=\frac{\sin \left(x\right)\cos ^{n-1}\left(x\right)}{n}+\frac{n-1}{n}\int \cos ^{n-2}\left(x\right)dx$

$\int \cos ^3\left(u\right)du=\frac{\sin \left(u\right)\cos ^2\left(u\right)}{3}+\frac{2\int \cos \left(u\right)du}{3}$

$=9\left(\frac{\sin \left(u\right)\cos ^2\left(u\right)}{3}+\frac{2\int \cos \left(u\right)du}{3}\right)$

Substitute Back u

$=9\left(\frac{\sin \left(\frac{x}{9}\right)\cos ^2\left(\frac{x}{9}\right)}{3}+\frac{2\sin \left(\frac{x}{9}\right)}{3}\right)$

$=\frac{3\sin \left(\frac{x}{9}\right)\left(\cos \left(\frac{2x}{9}\right)+5\right)}{2}$

Now add the Constant
$=\frac{3\sin \left(\frac{x}{9}\right)\left(\cos \left(\frac{2x}{9}\right)+5\right)}{2}+C$

Hope this Helps!